# How should I link objects from external .blend if they have modifiers?

Tags: modifiers, linked-data

I'm starting to learn how to do asset management for a project by linking from external blend files. I haven't figured out a good workflow for linking objectes that have modifiers on them. It's particularly ugly when the modifers reference other objects in the library (e.g., lattice) ***What is the standard workflow for dealing with linked objects that have modifiers relying on other objects in a lbrary?***

Here is what I've tried so far: In lib.blend, here's an object with a lattice modifier:

[image]

Here's how I link it in scene.blend:

1: Link the teapot <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd>

2: To be able to place it on a table in the scene, I make it a proxy object: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd>

3: Now the proxy object lost its modifiers, so I link the lattice object from lib.blend, and add a lattice modifier to my proxy teacup. (this is just an example - I've actually got quite a few modifiers on my asset)

4: Since I'm moving the teapot, I need to move the lattice object along with it (to keep the deformations sensible), so I make the lattice a proxy object.

[image]

This seems clunky. Is there a better way to manage assets from an external blend file?

Answer (score 1):

Usually the approach is to put all the related objects into a group, and then link that group.

Comment: I tried this method with an object that has Array + Curve modifiers, with start and end caps on the Curve modifier. Normally I'd put the caps on a separate render layer to ignore, but the entire linked group seems to be required to be on a single later. Is there a way to work around this?